# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError on Linux

Tags: java, linux, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a library that's been built on Linux and can be found here:

```
/test/lib/liblzo.so
```

I then have the following Java code:

import org.junit.Test;

```
public class CompressionTest {

    @Test
    public void testCompression() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("java.library.path=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("lzo");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Running this produces the following exception:

```
CompressionTest > testCompression FAILED
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lzo in java.library.path
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
            at CompressionTest.testCompression(CompressionTest.java:11)
```

Yet I can see from the standard out from the test that the path to my library is on the library path:

```
java.library.path=/test/lib
```

I've stripped the code back to the simplest setup and I still can't understand why the library is not loaded.  Could anyone advise what might be going wrong and how I might debug the issue more?

**Update**

I played with this a lot yesterday, as mentioned I sanitised the full `java.library.path` for this post, but I noticed that it was fairly long.  Long in the total length, but also that each directory on it was fairly nested (possible 8/9 levels).  I reduced the path to only include the directory I knew where the `so` library was and it worked.

Does anyone know of any `java.library.path` length constraints at all?

Comment: Please see my first comment in the post, it is already called that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative library path, and I suspect you'll find that your test framework is executing your file from a different directory. Confirm this by checking your current working directory:

```
System.out.println("user.dir=" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

To fix it, I suggest you set `java.library.path` to an absolute path so these things don't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to alter the path for the sake of this post. I've updated my original post, the paths on my library path are all absolute.

Comment: @imrichardcole Can you make a test case with no sensitive info so you can post the actual messages you're getting? Saying that it outputs "java.library.path=/test/lib" when it doesn't makes debugging way harder.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the liblzo.so inside some package and get it as resource?
Something like:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("package.liblzo.so");
```

Then youll dont have to worry again about the paths